# Using the colon in Azure Table Storage Partition Key yields odd results

Tags: azure-table-storage, illegal-characters

I have run into a truly perplexing situation which I hope I can get some assistance with. This code:

```
TableOperation retrieveOperation = TableOperation.Retrieve<T>(partitionKey, rowKey);
TableResult result = await table.ExecuteAsync(retrieveOperation);
T obj = result.Result as T;
```

The problem is with the partition key, which is on the form "Post:UID", example: `Post:f45ff69958e14342970a6ea88e7a009f`. **Inserting and retrieving data is fine**, but what is driving me crazy is that when I inspect the object after it has been retrieved, the "Post:"-part of the PartitionKey has been stripped from the object data. The partition key in the created object is just `f45ff69958e14342970a6ea88e7a009f`. This means that if I make changes to the object and try to do an `InsertOrReplace`-operation it will make a new record with just the part after the colon. I cannot for the life of me understand how this can happen.

I have tried to Google for illegal characters in partition keys, but cannot find anything about colon being an illegal character, so sorry if this is a FAQ.

Any help on this would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Perhaps you should just encode the PartitionKey? PartitionKey's and RowKey's do have some illegal characters but I have not heard of colon being on that list before. I'm sorry that I could not be more helpful.

Answer (score 0):

The colon is not an illegal character for the partition key. For more information on restricted characters see the "Characters Disallowed in Key Fields" section on [this](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/azure/dd179338.aspx) page.

Based on the code snippets above, I've created a loop that generate GUIDs of the same length and same "Post:" prefix and have not reproduced the issue. If the issue persists on your end, please post the entire section of code required to reproduce the issue.